# What happened to Dana and the 15th Armored Battalion?

Tags: robotech

The start of *Robotech: The Next Generation* explains what happened when the Invid invaded. The Army of the Southern Cross was apparently wiped out, but was Dana Sterling and the 15th Armored Battalion also wiped out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dana appears in the comics *Robotech: Love and War* and *Robotech: Prelude to the Shadow Chronicles* so it would seem that she survived the destruction of the 15th Armored Battalion and may have continued the war against the Invid in some capacity, but after that her fate in unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Now, there is a recently new movie called *Robotech: Love Live Alive* (2013) (adaptation of *Mospeada Love Live Alive* (1983) with some new animation) where you see Dana from the 15th squadron leaving Earth.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9txrDGHWnc

Dana heading to a Garfish spaceship to leave Earth.

[image]

In the movie *Robotech The Shadow Chronicles* it's confirmed they actually left with no problems because Louie from the 15th squadron is a secondary character.

[image]